Why does Reservoir Sampling page in wikipedia say that the size of the list is unknown, but the source code function knows the size?
reservoir sampling on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling

Reservoir sampling is a family of randomized algorithms for choosing a simple random sample, without replacement, of k items from a population of unknown size n in a single pass over the items. The size of the population n is not known to the algorithm and is typically too large for all n items to fit into main memory. The population is revealed to the algorithm over time, and the algorithm cannot look back at previous items. At any point, the current state of the algorithm must permit extraction of a simple random sample without replacement of size k over the part of the population seen so far.

Why does it say that the population n is not known to the algorithm, but then in the source code it is known? It literally takes as input the list length, and uses it to iterate. Are there some random sample functions that do know the list length and use it differently than here?
(* S has items to sample, R will contain the result *)
ReservoirSample(S[1..n], R[1..k])
  // fill the reservoir array
  for i := 1 to k
      R[i] := S[i]
  end

  // replace elements with gradually decreasing probability
  for i := k+1 to n
    (* randomInteger(a, b) generates a uniform integer from the inclusive range {a, ..., b} *)
    j := randomInteger(1, i)
    if j <= k
        R[j] := S[i]
    end
  end
end


There's a chance the Wikipedia page is wrong, you know. Anyone can edit it.

There is discrepancy between algorithm description and sample code. Algorithm itself works for unknown input size. Sample code is given for fixed sized input.

Because authors decided - it's simpler to show algorithm essence with given array. You can replace for-loop with while data available one and algorithm will work. Note that you can stop iterations in every moment (after k) and have reliable results for current n .
But look further - in descriptions of "Algorithm A-Res" and others they use while S has data loop that corresponds to "n is not known to the algorithm".
Yes, there is some inconsistency, but wiki page is written by many writers, some details remain imperfect...

You write: "It literally takes as input the list length"
That is not what is happening
In
ReservoirSample(S[1..n], R[1..k])
n is the number of samples to OUTPUT,  k is the first k INPUTS ( i.e. not all the inputs )

You are wrong, k is output size.
